# modus themes : Symbol’s function definition is void: modus-themes-load-themes

Tags: emacs

I try to install the modus themes on emacs 27.1

This is my config file (copy from the emacs doc, package installed via melpa):

```
(use-package modus-themes
  :ensure                         ; omit this to use the built-in themes
  :init
  ;; Add all your customizations prior to loading the themes
  (setq modus-themes-italic-constructs t
        modus-themes-bold-constructs nil
        modus-themes-region '(bg-only no-extend))

  ;; Load the theme files before enabling a theme (else you get an error).
  (modus-themes-load-themes)
  :config
  ;; Load the theme of your choice:
  (modus-themes-load-operandi) ;; OR (modus-themes-load-vivendi)
  :bind ("<f5>" . modus-themes-toggle))
```

after reload:

```
Error (use-package): modus-themes/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: modus-themes-load-themes
```

I don't know Elisp so I need your help

Ty.

Comment: This is not working; the themes are not loaded when Emacs start, and when I press F5 I have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed**
I changed the config file:

> ```
>       (require 'modus-themes)
>
>   ;; Add all your customizations prior to loading the themes
>   (setq modus-themes-italic-constructs t
>         modus-themes-bold-constructs nil)
>
>   ;; Load the theme of your choice.
>   (load-theme 'modus-operandi :no-confirm)
>
>   (define-key global-map (kbd "<f5>") #'modus-themes-toggle)
> ```